# How many elementary equivalent models are unifiable by ultrapower?

Tags: lo.logic, set-theory, ultrafilters, ultrapowers

**Definition.** A class $\mathcal{C}$ of pairwise elementary equivalent $\mathcal{L}$-structures is *unifiable by ultrapower* if there is an index set $I$ and an ultrafilter $F$ on it such that $\forall M,N\in \mathcal{C}~~~\prod_{F}M\cong \prod_{F}N$.

A theorem by Shelah and Keisler says that each set of elementary equivalent structures with size $2$ is unifiable by ultrapower.

**Question.** For which cardinal $\kappa$ the following assertion is true?

**Each set $\mathcal{C}$ of size $\kappa$ of pairwise elementary equivalent $\mathcal{L}$-structures is unifiable by ultrapower.**

**What about when $\mathcal{C}$ is a *proper class* of pairwise elementary equivalent $\mathcal{L}$-structures?**

The question is closely related to the problem of iterated ultrapowers.

Comment: No proper class can ever be unifiable, since the class must have elements of cardinality greater than (least cardinality of an elt. of the class)$^{\text{cardinality of the index set}}$. I'm pretty sure that every *set* is unifiable, though.

Comment: As far as I recall, the ultrafilter in Shelah's proof only depends on the cardinality of the structures and the language. So, yes, every set is unifiable.

Comment: @NoahS, isn't your comment over-stated? We could have a proper class consisting of copies of a single structure, and this is surely unifiable by an ultrapower. I guess you are thinking of a proper class of pairwise non-isomorphic structures.

Comment: @Joel, you're right of course. I need to be more careful when I talk about "structures" vs. "isomorphism -types of structures."

Answer (score 5):

A class $C$ of elementarily equivalent structures is unifiable by ultrapower if and only if the structures in $C$ have bounded cardinality (in other words, if they have a set of representatives up to isomorphism).

The left-to-right implication was given in Noah’s comment above: if we fix $M\in C$, then every $N\in C$ satisfies
$$|N|\le\Bigl|\prod_FN\Bigr|=\Bigl|\prod_FM\Bigr|=:\kappa.$$

As for the converse implication, Shelah proved in [Every two elementarily equivalent models have isomorphic ultrapowers](http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/BF02771574) something considerably stronger than just the Shelah–Keisler theorem:

> **Theorem (Shelah).** Let $\lambda$ be an infinite cardinal, and $\mu=\min\{\mu:\lambda^\mu>\lambda\}$. There exists an ultrafilter $F$ on $\lambda$ with the following property.
>
> Whenever $\{M_\alpha:\alpha<\lambda\}$ and $\{N_\alpha:\alpha<\lambda\}$ are sequences of models of cardinality $\le\kappa<\mu$ in the same language such that the ultraproducts $\prod_{\alpha<\lambda}M_\alpha/F$ and $\prod_{\alpha<\lambda}N_\alpha/F$ are elementarily equivalent, then they are isomorphic.
>
> In particular, if $M,N$ are elementarily equivalent models of cardinality $<\mu$, then the ultrapowers $M^\lambda/F$ and $N^\lambda/F$ are isomorphic.

Note that for a given $\kappa$, we can take e.g. $\lambda=2^\kappa$ to make $\mu>\kappa$.